# Unsure about a step in proving $e$ is transcendental

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, transcendental-numbers

I'm currently trying to understand the proof of e being transcendental in Julian Havil The Irrationals, but not sure how the following is concluded.

A polynomial of degree $mp+p-1$ is defined on the interval $0<x<m$ by
$$
  f(x) = \frac{x^{p-1}(x-1)^{p}(x-2)^p\dots(x-m)^p}{(p-1)!} 
$$

and then a function
\begin{equation}
  F(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{mp+p-1}f^{(k)}(x)   
\end{equation}

the sum of the derivatives essentially, stopping at the degree as everything after would be $0$.
Next he looks to evaluate $F(x)$ in two cases, $F(r)$, $r>0$, and $F(0)$ where $r$ is the positive integers up to $m$.

For the first case he states that the only way for the $k$th derivative to be non zero is for $k=p$, in which case theres a factor of $p!$ in the numerator of the derivative which cancels the $(p-1)!$ to leave $p$ in the numerator. This means that $F(r)$ for $r>0$ is an integer and has $p$ as a factor.

I see why the derivative must be $0$ for all $k<p$, and also see why it wont be for $k=p$. But for $p<k<pm+p-1$ why is it $0$? The factors have been differentiated out and we should be left with a polynomial?

Similarly, for the second case. He considers the $k$th derivative evaluated at $0$. Stating this is only non zero if $k=p-1$. But why is it zero if $p-1<k<pm+p-1$?

Comment: Pages 3-4 of [this derivation](https://math.colorado.edu/~rohi1040/expository/eistranscendental.pdf) seem to agree with you (see how $F(0) = \sum_{N = p-1}^\infty \cdots$ and $F(k) = \sum_{N = p}^\infty \cdots$ are sums of all the higher order derivatives $f^{(N)}$, and not just of the $p-1$ or $p$th order derivatives). Perhaps your book is mistaken.